# Unable to locate package python-gobject in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I installed all the Python packages by using this command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-gi-dbg
```

Later, I added all the repositories as shown

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

I am still getting this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-gobject
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-gobject
```

Comment: you are using `python3`. However the installation command line shows you're trying to install `gobject` for `python2`. Can you try: `sudo apt-get install python3-gobject`? And by the way the installation guid shows other spets to follow: https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#ubuntu-logo-ubuntu-debian-logo-debian

Comment: aalways put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install by running `apt update` before `apt install`, like this:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

you should do this before installing. it upgrades all the file, while the update only tells you about the no. of packages that should be installed.